# Fiddler Extension - Run IAutoTamper2 Logic When opening .saz

Tags: c#, fiddler

I use an `IAutoTamper2` to colorcode relevant requests/responses to my application based on url and other information.

This is very helpful for debugging. However when someone sends me a saved .saz file, I no longer see my helpful colorcodes. How can I apply the `IAutoTamper2` logic when a file is imported.

I looked at the `ISessionImporter` interface but you have to start from scratch. Is there a way to inherit from the default importer and add my logic that occurs in the `IAutoTamper2`?

I've looked at all the documentation about extensions on the telerik website but couldn't find anything relevant. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it. There is a **OnLoadSAZ** event that I can use to change loaded sessions.

This is my code:

```
    public void OnLoad()
    {
        FiddlerApplication.OnLoadSAZ += HandleLoadSaz;
    }

    private void HandleLoadSaz(object sender, FiddlerApplication.ReadSAZEventArgs e)
    {
        FiddlerApplication.UI.lvSessions.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (var session in e.arrSessions)
        {
            OnPeekAtResponseHeaders(session); //Run whatever function you use in IAutoTamper
            session.RefreshUI();
        }
        FiddlerApplication.UI.lvSessions.EndUpdate();
    }
```

I hope that helps someone else.